# Ignore all annotations using terraform kubernetes provider

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, annotations, ignore, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I want to implement the following behavior - without knowing the specific annotation names (which may be added over time without my knowledge) ignore them all via an `ignore_annotations` statement in the provider. Can this somehow be implemented? As I understand it, this instruction supports regular expressions, but I'm not sure that using `"*"` is the best option